# JPA 2.1 @Procedure with multiple out parameters

Tags: java, spring, jpa-2.1

Issue: call procedure with multiple out parameters.

```java
@Procedure(procedureName = "procedureName" , outputParameterName = "parma1", outputParameterName = "param2")
Map<String, String> methodName();
```

I am getting below error while calling method from service class.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null
        at org.hibernate.query.procedure.internal.ProcedureParameterImpl.setHibernateType(ProcedureParameterImpl.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.query.procedure.internal.ProcedureParameterImpl.<init>(ProcedureParameterImpl.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.registerParameter(ProcedureCallImpl.java:290)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.registerStoredProcedureParameter(ProcedureCallImpl.java:579)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.registerStoredProcedureParameter(ProcedureCallImpl.java:70)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.lambda$newAdhocStoredProcedureQuery$1(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:228)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:104)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head.forEach(IntPipeline.java:593)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.newAdhocStoredProcedureQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:219)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.createStoredProcedure(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:103)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.createQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:93)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detail given below web link http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-hibernate-jpa-2-1/ work for me.

Register the procedure manually as given below.

// Dynamic stored procedure definition.

```
StoredProcedureQuery addBookStoredProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("addBook_sp");
addBookStoredProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("sum", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT); 



/// call the stored procedure and get the result
query.execute();
Double sum = (Double) addBookStoredProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("sum");
```